# Timer interval increases as I activate extra timers

Tags: javascript

I have three timers in my code that can be set separately. However, when I activate more than one at a time the timer interval begins to increase and I am not sure where the problem originates.

Code is here: https://codepen.io/chicopwns98/pen/KKNogxM

HTML CODE HERE:

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="col3" >
            <h1 id="timer1">00:00</h1>
            <h3>mm:ss</h3>
            <button onclick="setTimer1()">Set</button>
            <button class="countUpButton" onclick="countUp1()">Count Up</button>
            <button class="countDownButton" onclick="countDown1()">Count Down</button>
            <button class="stopButton" onclick="stopTimer1()">Stop</button>
        </div>


        <div class="col3" >
            <h1 id="timer2">00:00</h1>
            <h3>mm:ss</h3>
            <button onclick="setTimer2()">Set</button>
            <button class="countUpButton" onclick="countUp2()">Count Up</button>
            <button class="countDownButton" onclick="countDown2()">Count Down</button>
            <button class="stopButton" onclick="stopTimer2()">Stop</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col3">
            <h1 id="timer3">00:00</h1>
            <h3>mm:ss</h3>
            <button onclick="setTimer3()">Set</button>
            <button class="countUpButton" onclick="countUp3()">Count Up</button>
            <button class="countDownButton" onclick="countDown3()">Count Down</button>
            <button class="stopButton" onclick="stopTimer3()">Stop</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: use separate variable for each timer

Answer (score 1):

`seconds`, `minutes` are global variable. Even though you are calling different add, sub function on countUp1, countUp2 and countUp3, the same `seconds` and `minutes` variable would increase.

For quick resolve, try creating three different `seconds` variable: `t1seconds`, `t2seconds`, `t3seconds` and use that variable in respective add, add2, add3 functions.

Similarly different minutes variable.

I have resolved it for the first timer:

https://codepen.io/subodhkalika/pen/qBqoagy

NOTE: On the above provided link, The timer 1 interval will increase by 1 sec however since the resolution is not there for t2 and t3 the bug exists on them.

You should now be able to identify the error.